# Убрать выбор из всех гридов при загрузке формы?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть два таба (Tabs)

Каждый из них, содержит по одному dataGridView1, dataGridView2

В загрузке формы, есть две функции, которые очищают выбор ячеек по умолчанию.

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
```

Проблема заключается в том, что функция срабатывает только dataGridView1 в Tab1, а в Tab2 ячейка в dataGridView2 остается выбранной.

Вопрос, как убрать выбор из всех гридов при загрузке формы?

Comment: нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879461/datagridview-without-selected-row-at-the-beginning). Вам стоит подробнее указывать в каком окружении работаете. Есть WinForms а есть WPF и я пытался найти ответ для WPF. Указывайте тег чтобы могли лучше вам помочь.

Comment: Решения данной проблемы нет, именно в такой форме как мне нужно было. Как выяснилось нельзя очистить ячейки от выделения сразу после загрузки в неактивных табах ! Можно решить с помощью евентов, таких как по клику на таб, гриды будут очищатся. Либо возможно это бы работало если бы загрузка была не динамической, а из сурса, как в вашем примере, тогда возможно тоже бы сработало, но к сожелению под логику работы не входит не один вариант, но решилось тем, что выделения эти - на самом деле только визуальные. Что не предпологалось ранее, то есть содержат -1.

Comment: Таким образом ограничился эвентом, по клику на таб. Если бы логика была другой, тогда возможно, вариант через bindsource срабатывал бы.